# To pass null values to float data type to add it into list

Tags: c#, list, xml-parsing, null

I am trying to pass the null value to float data type as follow,

```
float? period_final_value = null;
```

and getting the value in **period_final_value** from the parsing xml string as follows

```
var action = xmlAttributeCollection_for_period["value"];
xmlActionsone[j] = action.Value;
period_final_value = float.Parse(action.Value);
```

and then adding this obtained value to list as follows

```
serie_line.data.Add(period_final_value);
```

Defined my list as follows

```
var serie_line = new { name = series_name, data = new List<float?>() };
```

Now, My issue is when I am trying to pass value,it shold get add to the list, and moment when no value is recognized then it should add null has the value in the place of empty value in list but I don't know I am not able to get it work properly...my web service crashes moment it counters any blank value...any help will be greatly appreciated...

plz note...the var serie_line..I am going to serialize it into JSON format so that I can use those values to plot chart.

Comment: Could you rephrase that big paragraph? It's quite hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for `TryParse` instead of `Parse`.

When you call `period_final_value = float.Parse(action.Value);`, `Parse` will either parse the string into a `float` or throw an exception. It will never return `null`.

To get the behavior you want, try something like this:

```
float temp_value = 0;
float? period_final_value = null;
if (float.TryParse(action.Value, out temp_value)) {
    period_final_value = temp_value;
}

serie_line.data.Add(period_final_value);
```

If `action.Value` is a string representation of a number, then `period_final_value` will be that number. Otherwise, it will be `null`. You can then add it to your list of `float?` values.

Answer (score 0):

At this line

```
float? period_final_value = float.Parse(action.Value);
```

you are loosing the nullable float. When it fails to parse (there is no value or the value is not a valid float), it throws instead of returning null. `period_final_value` will never have `null` as a value.

See gleng's answer to be able to set null to `period_final_value`.